# What about recycling the helium used for sub-cooling the LOX in the tank of a rocket before launch?

Tags: launch, lox, helium, sub-cooled

Helium is a rare and expensive noble gas. When it is loaded into a rocket to be used after launch, it is not possible to recycle it. But the helium used for sub-cooling the LOX before launch (see question [Why would sub-cooled LOX tanks need to "topped-off" until the last minute or so?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/21345)) could be recycled. The mixture of helium and oxygen should be exhausted from the tank and separated by liquefaction. Is recycling of helium done when using sub-cooled LOX or is it vented into the atmosphere?

Comment: As noted on that thread: do we have any indication SpaceX uses this helium cooling method?